# Second Monitor suddently not recognized on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, multiple-monitors

So I had this problem originally when I first got Ubuntu on my PC but I managed to fix it.
However, for some reason it has appeared again.

I tried all these steps so far:

- purged Nvidia
- switched the HDMI cables
- changed to different drivers from additional drivers
- disabled secure boot

```
~$ xrandr

Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.97    59.96    59.93  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32
```

```
~$ lspci | grep VGA

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics (rev 05)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1f95 (rev a1)
```

```
~$ uname -r

5.10.0-1044-oem
```

Comment: Two monitors work for me in a laptop with an nvidia card with the built-in linux driver, which is used, when you remove the proprietary nvidia driver. Does your computer graphics work [well enough] with the built-in driver? See [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1356715/using-two-monitors-in-ubuntu-20-04/1357647#1357647.)

Comment: I've got a monitor connected to my laptop and experiencing the same issue. The monitor works with my older laptop with the same NVIDIA driver but older kernel (5.4.0-84-generic).