# How to connect it to another monitor to an old iMac running Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, mac, external-monitor

I have an old iMac 13.1. It was very slow, so I deleted its MacOS and installed Ubuntu 22.04.

On the back of this iMac there are two Thunderbolt ports. I bought a mini PD to HDMI cable, hoping that it can be used to connect to a Samsung 24" external monitor, but it seems that Ubuntu 20.04 does not detect the external monitor.

I was Googling but the results are for using an old iMac as monitor.
The Display settings look a bit primitive, and I'm not sure why.

[image: Display settings]

Comment: Thank you karel.

Comment: For me, the display is detected immediately (without restarting) in Kubuntu 22.04 and 23.04. Can you please edit and clearly mention whether you are using 20.04 or 22.04? Otherwise, it might confusing future users who would face a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

I followed instructions found here: [Using Two Monitors in Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1356715/using-two-monitors-in-ubuntu-20-04/1484467#1484467)

and restarted the Ubuntu iMac. Initially, the iMac restarted with blank screen, which scared me a bit. I then disconnect the cable and restarted the iMac again, some random red, blue and green lines appeared on the iMac screen. After sometimes, they gone away. I then connected the cable, open the Display settings and delighted to see this.
[image: Display settings]

Thank you so much.